# awk on different formatting

Tags: awk, grep

```
1       875091  G      GA     GT:AD:DP:BQ:SS:FT:DP4    0/1:.:5:.:1:VarscanHighConfidenceIndel:1,2,1,1
1       948846  T      TA     GT:DP:DP4:BQ:SS:FT:AD    1/1:50:10,0,10,0:.:1:VarscanHighConfidenceIndel:.
```

Hi I need to extract samples based on the quality . Samples are huge and i'm showing only certain column.

Column 5 represents the information for the values in column 6 separated by ':'. There other different formats in column 5 that im not showing here.

I need to extract samples of certain value. For example, I need DP > 12 and SS = 1 and other values for other formats.

In the first row, the DP , which is the 3rd element in column 5/6, is 5. The SS  = 1(element 5).

In the second row, the DP is the 2nd element in column 5/6 and the value is 50 and the SS=1 (element 5)

What I did was grouping all similar formats and did individual awk command to them.

```
gzip -dc file1.vcf.gz | grep 'GT:AD:DP:BQ:SS:FT:DP4' |awk -F "\t" 'NR>1 {split($6,a,":"); if(a[5]==1 && a[3]>12){print $0}}' 
gzip -dc file1.vcf.gz | grep 'GT:DP:DP4:BQ:SS:FT:AD' |awk -F "\t" 'NR>1 {split($6,a,":"); if(a[5]==1 && a[2]>12){print $0}}'
```

I'm looking a way to this without doing individual awk on different formats as there many other different formats in column 5.

Comment: Don't have time to write up a full answer but you can use `split($5, a, /:/)` then walk through the split-out fields (in `a`) finding the fields you want and `split($6, v, /:/)` and index into `v` based on the values you found in `a`.

Comment: you can remove grep and add a test for $5 like `gzip ... | awk -F"\t" 'NR>1 && $5 ~ /GT:AD...|GT:DP...|....../{split(....);....}'` Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the expected output given that input so it's not clear exactly what you want but the best general approach to these sorts of problems is to first create an array that maps field names to their values and then use that as you see fit, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
     split($5,n,/:/)
     split($6,v,/:/)
     for (i in n) {
        f[n[i]] = v[i]
     }
}
(f["DP"] > 5) && (f["SS"] == 1)

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       948846  T      TA     GT:DP:DP4:BQ:SS:FT:AD    1/1:50:10,0,10,0:.:1:VarscanHighConfidenceIndel:.
```